# Mutex not found even when OS reports that it exists

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am creating and using mutex in a windows service

```
using(var m = new Mutex(false,"mymutex")
{
    m.WaitOne();
    //to my things for a long time
    m.ReleaseMutex();
 }
```

On another program running with Administrator rights I do

```
Mutex.OpenExisting("mymutex")
```

and it throws mutex does not exist. I can see in the Resource manager that windows service has reference to the mutex.

What is wrong?

Comment: Could you please run your service as a normal program (or change how it's ran in services.msc to use your windows user credentials) and tell us if that helped? I think I know what's wrong, I'd like to make sure

Comment: What specific exception you get?

Comment: @WiktorZychla the standard WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operating system objects like Mutex have session scope.  Your service runs in session 0 so its mutex is not visible to processes that run on the desktop session.  The workaround is simple, prefix `Global\` to the mutex name.

Answer (score 0):

[Ignorance is not bliss. EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting throws WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException](http://blog.objectpattern.com/dot-net/ignorance-is-not-bliss-eventwaithandle-openexisting-throws-waithandlecannotbeopenedexception/)

It looks like the default behaviour changes from a Localsystem account to user account.