# C# MemoryMappedFile, how to set rights to communicate betweend processes?

Tags: c#, memory-mapped-files

I use memorymappedfile and it works when I communicate between 2 processes.
However, I set up a windows service that runs with the LOCAL SYSTEM account and I would like to communicate with processes that runs in the current domain account logged in.

I found accessrule and tried :

```
security.AddAccessRule(new AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>(string.Concat(Environment.MachineName, "\\Administrator"), MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
```

and also :

```
security.AddAccessRule(new AccessRule<MemoryMappedFileRights>("Everyone"), MemoryMappedFileRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
```

But did not work, how can I grant FULL ACCESS TO EVERYONE AND/OR ANONYMOUS LOGON whatever?

Comment: Can you post your code of how you open/create the MemoryMappedFile?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mutex not found even when OS reports that it exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8445063/mutex-not-found-even-when-os-reports-that-it-exists)

Comment: Jared, everything is here on msdn :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it!

Just put "Global\" in the segment name :

"Global\SegmentMemoryName" and put AccessRule to Everyone and you're done!